# Establishing Date Parameters by Date:Hour instead of just Date

Tags: sql

I have the current declared date parameters and "DATE" expression shown below.  It provides the data in terms of date only, excluding the 'by hour' detail.  I would like to change the below code to add the hour detail to the "DATE" field.

I'm an amateur in terms of SQL, so any suggestions help.

Here is the code...

```
Declare @Start_Date datetime, @End_Date datetime 
set @Start_Date = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101') 
set @End_Date = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())+7,0)) 
 ;

--Common Table Express1on (CTE) to get dates*****
With DateSequence( [Date] ) as 
(  Select @Start_Date as [Date]  
         union all 
    Select dateadd(day, 1, [Date])  
         from DateSequence  
         where Date < @End_Date)
```

Thanks in advance!

-Matt

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Change `dateadd(day, 1, [Date])` to `dateadd(hour, 1, [Date])`. In SQL Server this might reslt in  a *max recursion level* error, which can be solved adding `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 hour instead of 1 day:

```
with DateHourSequence as (
      select @Start_Date as yyyymmddhh
      union all 
      select dateadd(hour, 1, yyyymmddhh)  
      from DateHourSequence  
      where yyyymmddhh < @End_Date
    )
```